# What are the Touch Events available to Javascript on a os- Windows Mobile 6.1, device: Treo 800w, Opera 9.5 Gears Compatible

Tags: canvas, touchscreen

I am struggling to find any documentation on this subject.

I want to use a  tag to capture a signature via the touchscreen. It seems to recognize only "onclick".

What are the " touch events" that are available to Windows Mobile 6.x Opera Browser.
Does it convert mouseover, mousedown, mouseup  to ontouchstart, touchend etc..?

Thank you so much for any help/advice!

Answer (score 2):

The windows mobile browser does not support these events. I am not sure if in "windows mobile 7" they have introduced touch events, or atleast mousedown, mouse move. I have struggled a lot to have this working, but in vain. Only iphone, ipad and android OS supports the touch events.